# Count number of layers in a stack with value equal to raster pixel value

Tags: raster, r

I would like to count number of layers in a stack with value equal to raster pixel value. Here is my current try:

```
r1 <- calc(s, fun=function(x){sum(x == r)})
```

I get two errors

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

and

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Mb
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: how is r defined?

Comment: `r` is a raster file while `s` is a raster stack @obrl_soil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah ok, `raster::calc()` only operates on a single object, so your formula is essentially trying to total up all the occasions where one of your stack's cells equals a whole raster, which is never.

Try this: first, stack `r` and `s`. This means each pixel in the output stack becomes a vector where element 1 is the reference value and the rest are comparison values. Then run calc on that object, with a function like

```
function(x) {
  comp <- x[1]
  main <- x[2:length(x)]
  length(main[main == comp])
}
```

This should return a raster where each cell is a count of how many stack layers equal the overlying reference cell value.